# Finitely many isomorphism classes for finite index subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking for a classification/reference/theory for groups with the following property: every finite index subgroup of $G$ lies in one of finitely many isomorphism classes. I would also be interested to see this as a straightforward consequence of some other more well known classification. A simple example, beyond the obvious abelian ones, would be the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$. All the finite index subgroups are either isomorphic to $D_\infty$ or isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Classes of examples that satisfy the property are also of interest.

Comment: Is the set of isomorphism classes the same for every group you consider here?

Comment: That is of course interesting too, but it wasn't what I was thinking of. Just simply given $G$, there are only finitely many isomorphism classes for its finite index subgroups.

Comment: In that case, this includes the class of all finite groups (which are far from being classified).  As you probably know, the finite simple groups were classified in a monumental effort, but classifying all finite groups is apparently much more difficult.

Comment: I think that finitely generated virtually abelian groups, which include $D_\infty$ have that property, basically because there are only finitely many ways that a finite group can act on an $n$-generated abelian group and the associated cohomology groups are all finite. I don't know of any other examples.

Comment: @Qudit Don't forget that the finite groups are precisely the virtually trivial groups, so they can be ignored in the context of this question.

Comment: Yes, I think I should have stipulated infinite groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't understand how that helps.  Doesn't his question still implicitly ask for finite groups to be classified?

Comment: The infinite case just happened to be the one I was most interested in.

Comment: @RMiles I don't have a specific construction, but I suspect the restriction to infinite groups might not be enough.  I think maybe you could construct an infinite group from finite groups, such that if it were classified, then one would also classify the finite groups.

Comment: @RMiles Actually, I think $G \times \Bbb{Z}$ does the trick for any finite group $G$.

Comment: Yes, and I can see $G\times\mathbb{Z}^n$, for any positive integer $n$, as an example of the earlier comment by @Derek Holt.

Comment: Any group with no finite index proper subgroups, such as an infinite simple group, also satisfies the condition.

Comment: @RMiles Yes, it's virtually Abelian but I meant that $\Bbb{Z} \times G$ has $\Bbb{Z}$ and $G$ as characteristic subgroups, so if you know its structure then you also know the structure of $G$.